# SOAP server in flask python3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, soap, spyne

the `spyne` lib can create `wsdl`server, the wsdl example code:

```
from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.decorator import rpc
from spyne import ServiceBase, String
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server


class Test(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(String, _returns=String)
    def get_data(self, post_data):
        return process_xml_data(post_data)


app = Application([Test], 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope',
                  in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'), out_protocol=Soap11())
wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

so i am wondering is there a way to create `wsdl`service in `flask`?
`flask-spyne` is not support `python3` at all and it's already in life-end.

Comment: I may have found solution: [link](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples/flask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples/flask.
I verified and it's working.

Comment: Can you provide working example based on your question above?